# Rails 3, Rspec/Cucumber, and Factory Girl: No method error on nested/associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, rspec2, factory-bot

I've been bashing my head against a wall for a while on this one and I can't get it to work. I have three models:

```
class Instrument < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :analytical_methods
  has_many :analytes, :through => :analytical_methods
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :analytical_methods  
  attr_accessible :name, :analytical_methods_attributes
end

class AnalyticalMethod < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :instrument
  has_many :analytes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :analytes  
  attr_accessible :name, :analytes_attributes
end

class Analyte < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :analytical_method
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

And I have the following factories:

```
Factory.define :analyte do |analyte|
  analyte.name "Test analyte"
end  

Factory.define :analytical_method do |analytical_method|
  analytical_method.name "Test method"
  analytical_method.association :analyte
end  

Factory.define :instrument do |instrument|
  instrument.name "Test instrument"
  instrument.association :analytical_method
  instrument.association :analyte
end
```

Any time I try to Factory(:instrument) or Factory(:analytical_method), it throws the following error:

```
NoMethodError:  
  undefined method `analyte=' for #<AnalyticalMethod:0x00000104c44758>
```

Am I missing some ridiculous typo or something? The website works perfectly fine, but the tests keep failing. Thanks for any help in returning my sanity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because you're using `instrument.association :analyte` and `analytical_method.association :analyte` for a has_many relationship. The *association* declaration is used for belongs_to relationships.

I typically don't use Factory Girl to create `has_many` relationships, but if you choose to go this route, you're not the first person to do so. [Here's a blog post](http://ditoinfo.wordpress.com/2008/11/19/factory-girl-and-has_many-has_many-through-associations/) that's a few years old, but seems to describe what you're trying to do.